# Is there a way to mass edit user permissions / interact with hundreds of Google Sheets via Python?

Tags: python, pandas, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have around 600 google sheets that are all very similar where I need to get values from one specific column. I've authenticated an app in the Google Developer console so I have access to one sheet. However to do so I had to give access to the Service Account from inside the sheet itself. That service account does not have access to the other 599 sheets and I would rather not go through and manually give it access to each sheet.

Does anyone have an idea for a better way to do this, either by authenticating the service account for all sheets or a better way of accessing hundreds of google sheets via python that won't mean I have to permission the account? My google account has access to all of the sheets if that helps.

Had a google but can't figure out how to do this! Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Permissions: create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create) in Drive API to create a new permission to a specific file based on your preferred role.

### Sample Request via API explorer:

**FileId:** Sheet file id where you want to add new permission

```
{
  "role": "writer",
  "type": "user",
  "emailAddress": "serviceaccount@email.com"
}
```

---

Please refer here for more detailed explanation regarding the [Roles](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/ref-roles) to be used.

Since your Google Account has access to all of the sheets, you just need to get the list of all your sheet files' id and loop each id to create a new permission for your service account using your Google Account.

---

**Additional Reference:**

[Drive API Python Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python)